# Spring boot - Stand alone Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

How can i connect to an external neo4j server via Spring boot . I referred the example at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/ . Changed the following

```
@Bean
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    SpringRestGraphDatabase x = null;
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/");
}
```

But it is not working . Also when i installed neo4j it seems be secured with username password . What is the right way to connect to neo4j from spring boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the credentials were not being passed.

```
@Bean
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    SpringRestGraphDatabase x = null;

    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/",**"neo4j","nithin"**);
}
```

This worked ! . Thanks